# Can't bind to 'count' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have reconfigured some code and now receiving the error "Can't bind to 'count' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'"

Rather than have the notification component and notification-widget component.

I have now removed the notification component and only want to have the notification-widget component.

**Code before reconfiguration, which worked as expected:**

*notification-widget.component.html*

```
<div class="af-notification-widget">
    <notification [count]="config.count"></notification>
</div>
```

*notification-widget.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationConfigComponent } from '../../widget-creator/notification-config/notification-config.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'notification-widget',
  templateUrl: './notification-widget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification-widget.component.scss']
})
export class NotificationWidgetComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: NotificationConfigComponent;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

*notification.component.html*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < count">
    <div class="af-notification"
         (click)="itemRead(i)"
         routerLink="/budgeting/{{ item.url }}">
      <div class="af-notification__content">
        <span class="af-notification__title"
              [class.read]="item['read'] == true">{{ item['title'] }}
        </span>
        <span class="af-notification__description">{{ item['description'] }}</span>
        <span class="af-notification__date-time">{{ item['date'] }}</span>
      </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

*notification.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'notification',
  templateUrl: './notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification.component.scss']
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() count: number;
  items = [
    {
      title: 'Import of .......... failed',
      description:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
      date: '27/08/2019',
      read: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Manager ..........approved the budget and prices',
      description:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
      date: '26/08/2019',
      read: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Manager ..........approved the budget',
      description:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
      date: '26/08/2019',
      read: true
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  deleteWidget(i) {
    this.items.splice(i, 1);
  }
  itemRead(i) {
    if (this.items[i].read == false) {
      this.items[i].read = true;
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Rather than have the notification component and notification-widget component.

I have now removed the notification component and only want to have the notification-widget component.

**Code after removing notification component, which produces the error:**

*notification-widget.component.html*

```
<div class="af-notification-widget">
  <ng-container [count]="config.count" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i < count">
      <div class="af-notification" (click)="itemRead(i)" routerLink="/budgeting/{{ item.url }}">
        <div class="af-notification__content">
          <span class="af-notification__title" [class.read]="item['read'] == true">{{ item['title'] }}
          </span>
          <span class="af-notification__description">{{ item['description'] }}</span>
        <span class="af-notification__date-time">{{ item['date'] }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

*notification-widget.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationConfigComponent } from '../../widget-creator/notification-config/notification-config.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'notification-widget',
  templateUrl: './notification-widget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification-widget.component.scss']
})
export class NotificationWidgetComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: NotificationConfigComponent;
  @Input() count: number;
  items = [
    {
      title: 'Import of .......... failed',
      description:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
      date: '27/08/2019',
      read: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Manager ..........approved the budget and prices',
      description:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
      date: '26/08/2019',
      read: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Manager ..........approved the budget',
      description:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
      date: '26/08/2019',
      read: true
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  deleteWidget(i) {
    this.items.splice(i, 1);
  }
  itemRead(i) {
    if (this.items[i].read == false) {
      this.items[i].read = true;
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

*notification-config.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'notification-config',
  templateUrl: './notification-config.component.html'
})
export class NotificationConfigComponent {
  public count: number = 5;
  constructor() { }
}
```

*notification-config.component.html*

```
<form>
    Notifications:<br>
    <input min="1" name="notificationsRequired" type="number" [(ngModel)]="count" />
</form>
```

After removing the notification component and combining the code into the notification-widget component, I am unsure as to why I am receiving the error message - "Can't bind to 'count' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'"

Comment: just as the error message suggests... there is not count property on ng-container. actually there is no property on ng-container whatsoever, because ng-container doesn't exist at runtime in the dom. its a helper tag for strutcural directive like ngfor / ngif only.

Comment: What do you expect `<ng-container [count]="config.count"> to do? If ng-container was a component with an input named "count", that would make sense. But it's not. so?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I have added the notification-config files, this shows where the input 'count' is from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the @Input decorator from the count property, since you are setting it in the same component

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated count is not a property of ng-container which is why your code does not work. You should remove the [count]=config.count assignment from your ng-container. You can also remove the @input() count: number; as you don’t have any assignment to count anymore. The last thing that needs to be done is to change any reference to count in your html file since count is no longer a typescript variable. Just replace count with config.count and you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had to remove the property ('').

> //before with error
>
> ```
> @Input() ('name') name: any;
> ```

Console:Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

> //after without error
>
> ```
> @Input() name: any;
> ```